# Determining host app name for an app share or action extension?

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios-app-extension

I'm building a [Share App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) which can be run from 3rd party apps such as Safari, or Notes.

How can I determine the name of the host app to know if the clipped content is coming from Safari vs. Notes, for example?

If there is a bundle identifier such as `com.apple.mobilesafari` that I can access, that would be sufficient.

Comment: @Did you ever figure this out or any way of getting any other information about the host app or from the host app?